# How to generate JWT-Signature using RSA256 algorithm?

Tags: java, jwt, rsa, docusignapi, signature

I have a `PrivateKey` and a `PublicKey` and use the `privateKey` to init `Signature` and `publicKey` to verify the `Signature`:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 

// decode public key
X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKeyBytes);
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) 
keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);

//decode private key
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(prvKeyBytes);
RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) 
keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

//header and body Base64 decoded value
String headerString = mapper.writeValueAsString(header);
String headerEncoded = 
Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(headerString.getBytes());
String payloadString = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
String payloadEncoded = 
Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(payloadString.getBytes());
String tempAccessToken = hearderEncoded+"."+payloadString;

Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sign.initSign(privKey);
sign.update(tempAccessToken.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] signatureBytes = sign.sign();
sign.initVerify(pubKey);
sign.update(tempAccessToken.getBytes("UTF-8"));     

String jsonToken = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);
String JWTtoken = tempAccessToken + "." + jsonToken;
```

finally I get the JWT token below (dummy value):

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI4MzliN2NhNC02MDE1LTQ0OWQtOGZiNi02jkyYzk1Ny1jYTNjLTQyMWQtOTk2zY2VkNTAzZGViNWYiLCJleHAiOjE1MzIwMDQwMTcsImF1ZCI6ImFjY291bnQtZC5kb2N1c2lnbi5jb20iLzY29wZSI6InNpZ25hdHVyZSBpbXBlcnNvbmF0aW9uIn0=.YNZzR0HgPWFm4dXMMHn3czEDRukYUB0Hyw7YP_BGY2dniIMqpH4Ctz5EEHcHrNT_mGImcp026w-isYgv56TTugYnkcAs8HH0YXa1Ey0skdjVYoZHdeyPC8Ci9xeOQF9wf4VjrBboaRxWkVXfngOHHewpV42NcaXxwmGlresWukHVmmjbFokd1Cm5BJKVhVlsZWuftcJlC3XoO9REjaZX78YTY9S5bpXmsZBYr20wHsWJrkP9EWGf7WSGHVXGBJfCpvOTZDC8_4B12ToD_RKjk6n5s8-F7X54KY4kx6Gg7xnk55vDw==

I'm not able to get the `accessToken` using this JWT Token. I will get the response instead:

> "error" :"invalid_request";

**NOTE**: I am using this JWT token to get the access token for **DocuSign Application**.

Comment: The token is invalid. You should include in the question the code which is building `tempAccessToken`. surely the problem is that you are coding to base64 and it should be base64url

Comment: I have added the code which is used to get the tempAccessToken.

Comment: Your token is not base64url encoded. Review `base64url` method. Have you included in the question a token that corresponds to the code? It does not seem updated

Comment: [DocuSign link](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken#step-1-request-the-authorization-code) I have get the header and payload Base64 encoded value and add "."  between the values as per the doc.

Comment: No, it is saying **base64 url encoded** `rs256sign(<base64URL-encoded header>.<base64URL-encoded body>)` . The JWT parts must be encoded in **base64url**. See [RFC7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519)

Comment: I have updated the code(above).I dono it was rite..can u confirm the above one was right?

Comment: The code seems correct now( fixing some typo), but the easiest way to check it is executing it. Note that for testing it in jwt.io you will need to export the public key as PEM